# How to Upload file from windows directory using selenium2library and Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Can someone help me How to Upload file from windows directory using selenium2library and Robot Framework.I have tried using Choose File command in selenium2library but I am getting error as File doesn't exist in local file system.I am not sure whether directory path is not considered or any other issue. Please give me valid code or any alternate solution.Any help would be appreciated.Following is the command I have tried

```
Choose file     xpath = //input[@firmware-upgrade='firmware']       /Downloads/Cambium_Builds/Falcon/ePMP1000-Hotspot-2.5.1-b3.tar
```

HTML tag is `

[image: Image location and HTML tag]`

Comment: Use this site and try it on your own. But this uses Auto IT not Robot. Both tools are used to handle windows based pop ups. So give this a try. GoodLuck. http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: You need to provide the full path.

Comment: @FlorentB. It is unable to detect after giving full path.Tried following path.         Choose file  xpath = //input[@firmware-upgrade='firmware']  C:/Users/mra001/Downloads/Cambium_Builds/Falcon/ePMP1000-Hotspot-2.5.1-b3.tar

Comment: Have you tried with the file scheme: `file:///C:/Users/...` ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't upload those files using just selenium?

Comment: @FlorentB. can you please help me with an example , I dont know about file scheme .

Comment: @RemcoW I dont know how to try with others other than selenium,if you can help me how to do that with an example,i will be very happy

Comment: @Madhu, just try with `file:///C:/Users/mra001/Downloads/Cambium_Builds/‌​Falcon/ePMP1000-Hotspot-2.5.1-b3.tar` or `C:\\Users\\mra001\\Downloads\\Cambium_Builds\\Falcon\\ePMP1000-Hotspot-2.5.1-b3.tar`

Comment: @Madhu See the answer I've given.

Comment: The error you are getting is coming from Selenium2Library. It uses os.path.isfile to check that the file exists and is actually a file. I'm sure you checked that the file exists so maybe its a permissions problem.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks every one for your answers and time,but luckily following script helped my uploading a file from windows and its working fine.There might be different options to perform the same using AutoIT but I have tried with whatever i know.

```
***Settings***
Library  Selenium2Library


*** Variables ***
${Browser_Chrome}           Chrome
${Device_77_URL}        https://10.110.0.17
${Device_Path}          C:\\Users\\mra001\\Downloads\\Builds\\Gambit\\500-2.5.1-b3.img

*** Keywords ***


Software Update 
    Open Browser    ${Device_77_URL}    Chrome
    Input Text      id=Username  admin
    Input Text      password=Password    admin
    Click Button    xpath = //button[@type='submit']
    Wait Until Element Is Visible       //a[text()='Home']      20
    Click Link      xpath = //a[text()='Operations ']
    Input Text  xpath = //input[@firmware-upgrade='firmware']  ${Device_Path}
    Click Button        Upgrade Firmware
    Sleep       70
    Confirm Action
    Close Browser
```

Comment: Irrelevant to the question but still: you could save some time if you changed  `Sleep       70` to another `Wait Until Element Is Visible`.

Comment: @jim  I know its irrelevant to question that I have asked but I have experimented  with AutoIT and other options , that didnt work for me.I have tried with whatever I know. I will use wait until element is visible instead of sleep..Thanks for your comment

Comment: Thx. Double backslashes, what the heck. Few hours of searching because of this.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the browse button to open the popup using Robot Framework you can do something like the following to submit a file.

```
public static void robotwrite() throws Exception{
    try{
        RobotWrite rw = new RobotWrite();
        rw.type("C:\\Desktop\\Example.docx");
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(VK_ENTER);
        r.keyRelease(VK_ENTER);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.error("Could not write");
        throw(e);
    }
}
```

Robot Class

```
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class RobotWrite {

    private Robot robot;

    public RobotWrite() throws AWTException {
        this.robot = new Robot();
    }



    public void type(CharSequence characters) throws AWTException {
        int length = characters.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char character = characters.charAt(i);
            type(character);
        }
    }

    public void type(char character) throws AWTException {
        switch (character) {
        case 'a': doType(VK_A); break;
        case 'b': doType(VK_B); break;
        case 'c': doType(VK_C); break;
        case 'd': doType(VK_D); break;
        case 'e': doType(VK_E); break;
        case 'f': doType(VK_F); break;
        case 'g': doType(VK_G); break;
        case 'h': doType(VK_H); break;
        case 'i': doType(VK_I); break;
        case 'j': doType(VK_J); break;
        case 'k': doType(VK_K); break;
        case 'l': doType(VK_L); break;
        case 'm': doType(VK_M); break;
        case 'n': doType(VK_N); break;
        case 'o': doType(VK_O); break;
        case 'p': doType(VK_P); break;
        case 'q': doType(VK_Q); break;
        case 'r': doType(VK_R); break;
        case 's': doType(VK_S); break;
        case 't': doType(VK_T); break;
        case 'u': doType(VK_U); break;
        case 'v': doType(VK_V); break;
        case 'w': doType(VK_W); break;
        case 'x': doType(VK_X); break;
        case 'y': doType(VK_Y); break;
        case 'z': doType(VK_Z); break;
        case 'A': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_A); break;
        case 'B': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_B); break;
        case 'C': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_C); break;
        case 'D': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_D); break;
        case 'E': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_E); break;
        case 'F': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_F); break;
        case 'G': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_G); break;
        case 'H': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_H); break;
        case 'I': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_I); break;
        case 'J': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_J); break;
        case 'K': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_K); break;
        case 'L': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_L); break;
        case 'M': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_M); break;
        case 'N': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_N); break;
        case 'O': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_O); break;
        case 'P': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_P); break;
        case 'Q': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Q); break;
        case 'R': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_R); break;
        case 'S': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_S); break;
        case 'T': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_T); break;
        case 'U': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_U); break;
        case 'V': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_V); break;
        case 'W': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_W); break;
        case 'X': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_X); break;
        case 'Y': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Y); break;
        case 'Z': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Z); break;
        case '`': doType(VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
        case '0': doType(VK_0); break;
        case '1': doType(VK_1); break;
        case '2': doType(VK_2); break;
        case '3': doType(VK_3); break;
        case '4': doType(VK_4); break;
        case '5': doType(VK_5); break;
        case '6': doType(VK_6); break;
        case '7': doType(VK_7); break;
        case '8': doType(VK_8); break;
        case '9': doType(VK_9); break;
        case '-': doType(VK_MINUS); break;
        case '=': doType(VK_EQUALS); break;
        case '~': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
        case '!': doType(VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK); break;
        case '@': doType(VK_AT); break;
        case '#': doType(VK_NUMBER_SIGN); break;
        case '$': doType(VK_DOLLAR); break;
        case '%': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_5); break;
        case '^': doType(VK_CIRCUMFLEX); break;
        case '&': doType(VK_AMPERSAND); break;
        case '*': doType(VK_ASTERISK); break;
        case '(': doType(VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS); break;
        case ')': doType(VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS); break;
        case '_': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS); robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); break;
        case '+': doType(VK_PLUS); break;
        case '\t': doType(VK_TAB); break;
        case '\n': doType(VK_ENTER); break;
        case '[': doType(VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
        case ']': doType(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
        case '\\': doType(VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
        case '{': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
        case '}': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
        case '|': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
        case ';': doType(VK_SEMICOLON); break;
        case ':': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); break;
        case '\'': doType(VK_QUOTE); break;
        case '"': doType(VK_QUOTEDBL); break;
        case ',': doType(VK_COMMA); break;
        case '<': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_COMMA); break;
        case '.': doType(VK_PERIOD); break;
        case '>': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_PERIOD); break;
        case '/': doType(VK_SLASH); break;
        case '?': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_SLASH); break;
        case ' ': doType(VK_SPACE); break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot type character " + character);
        }
    }

    private void doType(int... keyCodes) {
        doType(keyCodes, 0, keyCodes.length);
    }

    private void doType(int[] keyCodes, int offset, int length) {
        if (length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        robot.keyPress(keyCodes[offset]);
        doType(keyCodes, offset + 1, length - 1);
        robot.keyRelease(keyCodes[offset]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Selenium provides the option to upload files using the send_keys() method. I don't know what language you are using so I'll provide an example in Python.

In the screenshot I can see that this is your input element:

```
<input type="file" firmware-upgrade="firmware"/>
```

Assume you have found this element and saved in the element variable.
If we want to upload a file to this all we need to do is use the send_keys() method and give the filepath as argument.

```
element = function_to_locate_element()
element.send_keys('path\\to\\file')
```

This way there is no need to use the robot for this.

Comment: Instead of giving a solution to the author's extremely simple problem (that's what Florent did btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183182/how-to-upload-file-from-windows-directory-using-selenium2library-and-robot-frame/37189445?noredirect=1#comment61907295_37183182) you advised him to switch the framework. How is that helpful exactly?

Comment: He is already using selenium. He wants to do a file upload and uses a Robot framework for this (most likely because selenium can't deal with OS level dialogs). All I'm suggesting is he might want to make use of the uploading functionality that comes with selenium instead of using the robot for this.

Comment: This is not how RF works, you don't include it along selenium. RF itself utilizes selenium as one of the underlying drivers. If you had known what Robot Framework is and how it actually works, you wouldn't have made this mistake.

Comment: That might be true and I might have made a mistake. However I do think the question should not be tagged with 'selenium' if the asker isn't using this. selenium2library would've been sufficient.

Comment: You very well may be correct on this. I would also like to apologise for being inappropriately harsh.